# Conjure-up - what happened to the Openstack with MAAS option?

Tags: 16.04, maas, openstack, conjure-up

I am trying to understand what happened to the conjure openstack spell.  When I conjure-up openstack, the only two options that exist are:

```
Openstack with NovaKVM (this is relatively new)  
Openstack with NovaLXD (this has been around which targets the local install).
```

I am running:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 server  
conjure-up 2.1.0-0~201702050449~ubuntu16.04.1  
maas 2.2.0~beta1+bzr5675-0ubuntu1~16.04.1  
juju 2.1-beta5-xenial-amd64
```

I can't figure out what happened to the original choice of Openstack with MAAS? With that said, I did build a MAAS cloud using juju and force conjure-up to use it (I think the term was headless).  Technically it did work BUT...  Instead of the original option where it needed 5 nodes - one for the juju controller, and 4 for the remaining openstack services (using containers- which is what I want), it was going to use 17 physical machines. One for the juju controller, and then 16 physical machines to deploy each of the 16 services.

What am I missing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, since I am new to AskUbuntu, when someone either edits, or suggest an edit to a post - that doesn't appear to enhance the technical merit / relevance of the question, why bother?  Fixing a character from lower case to uppercase, or remove html "<br>" tags, seems overly picky, no?  Like I said, just curious.

Comment: Your question will be here forever, so allowing others to make minor and sometimes insignificant edits, helps preserve the quality of the site, and question.  So, in this case, it's taking a good question and making it better, no matter how slight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we updated the name to `OpenStack with NovaKVM` to indicate a normal openstack installation. This name does need some work to also incorporate the use of MAAS.

I've created a bug https://github.com/conjure-up/spells/issues/44 and would love people's input on a better name that incorporates both technologies.